Datastax-studio Casendra DB-6.8.32 unable to find java executable(windows)?
Datastax unable to find java executable even after uninstalling and reinstalling java.
I have both jdk-17 and jdk-8 installed in my system, as datastax uses jdk-8 and my applications are running on jdk-17 so always I use set path to set the path of jdk-8 and start the server.bat. But recently I am facing an issue that datastax was not able to find the java executable in the specified path even after executing the command java -version gives me the correct path.
Steps I followed(windows)

Uninstalled java(all versions)
Reinstalled java(jdk-8) and set the path in the environment viriable.
Remove .datastax from users folder

Still the problem persists, is there any other workaround I need to follw to fix this issue?

What do you mean by "Datastax unable to find java executable"? DataStax is the name of the company so your post doesn't make sense. Please provide background info, sample code, full error messages and stacktrace so we have an idea what your problem is. Cheers!

DataStax is a company name and it is unclear which product you're referring on here. Could you please fix that?
Also, from a cursory look at their documentation, I see no Windows compatibility for their main database product offering (DataStax Enterprise (DSE)).
There may be other alternatives that you may want to look here,

Running on docker - https://docs.datastax.com/en/docker/overview/docker-about.html and https://www.datastax.com/blog/running-dse-microsoft-windows-using-docker and https://www.datastax.com/blog/running-dse-microsoft-windows-using-docker and https://github.com/datastax/docker-images for instructions
Running on Windows Sub-system for Linux (WSL) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment

In terms of the Java version/compatibility, I can already see that their DSE product supports Java 11 for core Cassandra workloads beginning a minimum version of 6.8.22. Note that the latest version as of this writing is at 6.8.48 and you may want to subscribe to their release announcements by following this procedure for any newer versions and announcements.
Also, if you're running a supported subscription and have a valid license for the DSE software, you could reach out to their support at their support portal for further help.

It's this one Madhavan, https://www.datastax.com/dev/datastax-studio - not often used though.

sorry, what do you mean by not often used though? :thinking:. Are you using it as part of the WSL on Windows? Checkout out the Studio docs here for various configs about it and troubleshooting steps.
